# Run a wordpress site from one computer to another in localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, wamp

I have a Wordpress site on one of my computers. Now I want to run that site in another computer locally (xampp or wamp).
For that, I zipped all files from that folder with database SQL file and extract that zipped file in another PC xampp htdocs folder. Created DB and imported the SQL file in the database.

But while running the site it gives an error

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /Ullash/builders/index.php was not found on this server.

I added the below code in `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/Projects/new-ullash/builders' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/Projects/new-ullash/builders' );
```

But still the error same.

Anybody Help Please ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the solution.
Add below code in `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'site url' ); // site url sample : http://localhost/Projects/new-ullash/builders
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'site url' ); // site url sample : http://localhost/Projects/new-ullash/builders
```

And also change the projects path in`.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Projects/new-ullash/builders/  // change project path here
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Projects/new-ullash/builders/index.php [L] // change project path here
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do everything in cleaner and faster, then install All in one Migration
https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/